# Align layout at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android

I would like to have the same as on the enclosed image with the scanning information widgets (progressbar, textview and button) to stay at the bottom of the screen. However when I run my app they go at the top of the screen when the ListView is empty.

[image]

I tried a lot of methods described in other topics, but I still could not make it work.

Do you have some suggestions about which layout I should use in this case?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListViewDevices"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ListViewDevices">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBarDevice"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/lblScanningStatus"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblScanningStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="@string/scan_in_progress"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBarDevice" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPauseScan"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/pause_scan"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I did it an app I worked on previously. Using a RelativeLayout as the main shell we are able to position elements in any way inside it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/grey_font">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarDevice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblScanningStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/progressBarDevice"
            android:text="Scanning" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/orange_pay"
            android:id="@+id/btnPauseScan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="PAUSE" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: snapshot of layout]

Answer (score 0):

I would first simplify the layout by flattening it slightly.  Removed the FrameLayout that holds the bottom Constraint..  Then made the listViewDevices constrain bottom to top of the bottom contraint layout (which i have called scanner)..

Looks correct in my layout editor.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListViewDevices"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/scanner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/scanner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ListViewDevices"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarDevice"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/lblScanningStatus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblScanningStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="SCANNING FOR NEW DEVICES..."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBarDevice" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPauseScan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="PAUSE"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather prefer to add LinearLayout as root layout.
So when you scroll down or up then it will not scroll with your layout when its empty.

So when your listview is empty then also it will be in the bottom of the screen only.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListViewDevices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ListViewDevices">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBarDevice"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/lblScanningStatus"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblScanningStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="@string/scan_in_progress"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBarDevice" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPauseScan"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/pause_scan"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers but none of them works. Sometimes it looks fine in Android Studio but when I test my application on a real phone the widgets are displayed on top of the screen.
If I will find a working solution I will post it here.